# A basic question related with the order of convergence of iterative method

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I am working on an iteration problem for computing inverse of a non singular matrix $A$

I have got following relationship between error matrix defined by $E_k  = X_k-A^{-1}$. 
$\|E_{k+1} \|\leq (1-\beta)E_{k}+\beta E_{k}^3$, $k =0,1,\ldots$,   $0<\beta\leq 1$

From here can we conclude that $\|E_{k+1} \|\rightarrow 0$ if $k\rightarrow \infty$ provided 
$\|E_{0} \|< 1$.
What can we say about order of convergence of my iterative method? Could we conclude that order of convergence is 3 for $\beta= 1$ and it has linear convergence for $\beta$ not equal to 1.

Could anybody help me with this?I would be very much thankful.

Comment: How is $X_k$ evaluated?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Where is the problem? Here is the definition of order I'm using: a method converges with order $q$ if $\lim_{k\to\infty} \|E_{k+1}\|/\|E_k\|^q$ is finite (and smaller than 1 in the case $q=1$).

Comment: @JitseNiesen Thank you very much sir. I was bit confused. I wanted to know could we draw the same conclusion as I have written above.